# How to make files and folder that belong to www-data, readable and writable by my user using sFTP

Tags: permissions, ssh, sftp

I've configured Wordpress on an Ubuntu server v18 and assigned all files and directories the group `www-data` and assigned them to the user `www-data`: this way I should be able to update Wordpress from the web interface.

I'd also like to edit files using FileZilla od PHPStorm and to connect to my server I use sFTP.

The problem is that, as the files and directories are assigned to `www-data`, I cannot edit or remove files and directories.

I've tried to add my user to the group `www-data`, but I'm still not able to edit or remove them.

How can I set permissions, users and groups in a way that both Wordpress and I are able to edit and remove files and directories?

Answer (score 0):

The best method (in my opinion) would be to use `/etc/crontab` to start a script or a service with a directorywatcher. The latter is very easy to make with the [watchdog module in python](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/).

In that script you would then first make a timestamped backup before moving files to the webservers directories. Both `/etc/crontab`  and a service would allow you to copy the files as the user `www-data`.

A directorywatcher would watch over the FTP directory you use to put files on the server (and that would be a dedicated directory not related to the webservers directories). That makes it a bit more secure too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions? is it 700 or 770?

Permissions are like this:

3 sets

- User
- Group
- All

In each of these sets, there is a directive or a permission level

- Read
- Write
- Execute

So, at the end you see it:

700 = rwx------ ==> Only user can read, write and execute
770 = rwxrwx--- ==> User and group can read, write and execute
777 = rwxrwxrwx ==> All users and groups can read, write and execute
600 = r-x------ ==> Only the user can read and execute but can't execute

This is computed in binary based 0 and 1 .. If a bit is enabled, it will be 1 else it will be 0

So, 700 is actually 7-0-0 or in Binary 111-000-000
770 is 111-111-000
600 is 101-000-000

So, if the other user is in the group, you need to ensure that the group has read permission on the files, write and execute if necessary.

You will need on of these permissions where 'x' is your current permission level for the file owner:

x00 ==> Group has no permission
x10 ==> Group has execute permission only on the file
x20 ==> Group has write permission only on the file
x30 ==> Group has write and execute permissions on the file
x40 ==> Group has read permission only on the file
x50 ==> Group has read and execute permissions on the file
x60 ==> Group has read and write permissions on the file
x70 ==> Group has all access